# Php Session variable is not passing to second page

Tags: php

it seems to be simple but anyhow i can't pass my sessionvariable from the first page to the second page.
I have searched for solutions but can't find any. As far as i know i am starting the session on bothe pages before sending any headers.

code on page1

```
<?php session_start()?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">


<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

}

?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Code on page 2

```
<?php session_start()?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 

    echo "This is from my session: "." ". $_SESSION['username'];

?>


</body>
</html>
```

So on the second page (page2.php) i get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\page2.php on
>   line 12

This is from my session:

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: The php code you have on page 1 must be on page 2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There upvoted answer works fine. The below should also work. I think the basic thing is to check if a session can be passed from one page to another. Please see the below code. Two things basically - 1. Form action should be set to same page & 2. Redirect after session is set

Note: No change is needed for page2.php

```
<?php session_start()?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
        <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            header("Location: page2.php");
        }

        ?>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

Your form posts to `page2.php`, so the session-setting bit isn't being reached on `page1.php`
You need to add that code to `page2.php` instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

Comment: just a note: better to use `!empty` in place of `isset()` - `isset()` just checks if the var/key exists - not if the value doesn't equal an empty value (e.g. '')

Comment: Wowwww this was my first question on stackoverflow and i had reply's immediately. Thnx Lawra your answer worked.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs: thnx for the tip will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code - the mistake is on page2.php, you submit the form to page2.php but you didn't set any value in page2.php.

It should be like this:

page1

```
<?php session_start()?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>    

<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

page 2

```
    <?php session_start()?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php 

    if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    }
    echo "This is from my session: "." ". $_SESSION['username'];

    ?>


    </body>
    </html>
```